# Is it possible to suppress notifications in Android?

Tags: android, notifications

I'd like to be able to listen for notifications being sent to the status bar, and intercept and suppress (temporarily) those notifications.

I've seen [AccessabilityEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityEvent.html).[TYPE_NOTIFICATION_STATE_CHANGED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityEvent.html#TYPE_NOTIFICATION_STATE_CHANGED), and [NotificationListenerService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html).

However, I just don't want to be informed when a notification is displayed, I want to prevent the notification from being displayed.

I can see how this could potentially be a security threat, so I can understand if it's not possible. Is this possible? If so, how would I go about doing it?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're on the right track with the NotificationListenerService. Google has made these API's available from Android 4.3 on, so an application using this method would just be available for new devices.

In the following blogpost you can find an example of what you can do with the NotificationListenerService: http://weimenglee.blogspot.ch/2014/03/android-tip-notification-listener.html

The basic idea is to implement the `onNotificationPosted()` method, which gives you a `StatusBarNotification` instance. You should then be able to cancel the notification with `this.cancelNotification(
        notif.getPackageName(),
        notif.getTag(),
        notif.getId());`

See the blogpost for a further description of what to extend and how to implement the methods.

Hope this helps.

Comment: If I cancel the notification, can I resubmit it later? Will it show up in the status bar and then disappear, or not show up at all?

Comment: I have never tried it, but I assume it should be possible. It will be up to your app to build the notification, but you can store all the important data (Intent, content, and so on) from the StatusBarNotification object for later use.